# When is binding a reference to a temporary allowed in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

As the title suggests, which of the following examples is legal C++ according to the C++20 standard?

```
inline constexpr auto const& v = bool{}; // #1 - all ok
static_assert([]{
    constexpr auto const& x = bool{}; // #2 - clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok
    return not x;
}());
struct s { constexpr s(auto const&) {} };
static_assert([]<s = bool{}>{ return true; }()); // #3 - clang nope, gcc ok, msvc ok
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/3Y5G11E9r)

---

The error message from Clang with example `#2`:

```
<source>:5:27: error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant
expression
    5 |     constexpr auto const& x = bool{};
      |                           ^   ~~~~~~
<source>:5:27: note: reference to temporary is not a constant expression
<source>:5:31: note: temporary created here
    5 |     constexpr auto const& x = bool{};
      |
```

The error message from GCC with example `#2`:

```
<source>:5:36: error: '<anonymous>' is not a constant expression
    5 |     constexpr auto const& x = bool{};
      |                                    ^
<source>: At global scope:
<source>:7:2: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    4 | static_assert([]{
      |               ~~~
    5 |     constexpr auto const& x = bool{};
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    6 |     return not x;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    7 | }());
      | ~^~
<source>:7:2: error: '<lambda()>' called in a constant expression
<source>:4:15: note: '<lambda()>' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
    4 | static_assert([]{
      |               ^
```

The error message from Clang with example `#3`:

```
<source>:10:15: error: no matching function for call to object of type
'(lambda at <source>:10:15)'
   10 | static_assert([]<s = bool{}>{ return true; }());
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:15: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: conversion
from 'bool' to 's' in converted constant expression would bind reference to a
temporary
   10 | static_assert([]<s = bool{}>{ return true; }());
      |               ^      ~~~~
```

Comment: Try `/permissive-` with MSVC, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170

Comment: @PaulSanders There is a link to a live example which compiles the code for all three compilers (Clang, GCC, and MSVC), of which MSVC already has enabled the `/permissive-` flag. Also note that there is a discrepancy between Clang and GCC, which both use the equivalent `-pedantic` flag.

Comment: Cleaner godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/zdTx6rn3n

Comment: @MarekR Thanks, but that Godbolt setup is missing the compilers version from trunk. This is important because a successful compilation with a build from trunk can be an indication that the issue is already known to the compiler implementors. Also, the view from that setup makes it less convenient to copy compiler output from.

Comment: _There is a link to a live example..._ sorry, my bad

Comment: (Typical MSVC...)

Answer (score 5):

The rule here<sup>†</sup> is currently that a `constexpr` reference *must* refer to an object with static storage duration (this is the "permitted result" rule in what is now [[expr.const]/13](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#13)). That is, a `constexpr` reference has to have an address that is a constant expression. This is something that a lot of people find surprising, in that this is ill-formed:

```cpp
void f() {
    constexpr int a = 1;    // ok
    constexpr auto* p = &a; // error
}
```

Because `p` needs to point to something with constant address, and `a` has a different address every time `f` is invoked. So this doesn't work.

This is the rule that explains what's going on with your example. This is okay because of `inline`:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto const& v = bool{}; // #1 - all ok
```

The temporary object is lifetime extended to be the lifetime of `v`, and `v` has static storage duration. That's a constant address.

But this is not okay for the same reason my short example isn't okay (MSVC is technically wrong to accept this) - `x` here is just a local variable, the object it refers to doesn't have constant address.

```cpp
static_assert([]{
    constexpr auto const& x = bool{}; // #2 - clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok
    return not x;
}());
```

---

<sup>†</sup>At least the current rule says this. This is a fairly confusing rule and prevents a lot of reasonable-looking code from working. The most prominent such reasonable-looking code is structured bindings:

```cpp
void f() {
    constexpr auto t1 = std::tuple(1)
    static_assert(std::get<0>(t1) == 0); // ok

    constexpr auto [t2] = std::tuple(2); // error
}
```

That's because under the hood, the declaration of `t2` is declaring a constexpr reference, to a local variable.

The current direction, in [P2686](https://wg21.link/p2686), is something called "symbolic addressing". That is, we treat the original example not as trying to initialize `p` with having a constant address (which doesn't work) but rather as having the definition "address of variable `a`" (relying on the fact that it's always the address of `a`, even if that address isn't constant). You still wouldn't be able to use `p` as a non-type template parameter (for reasons that I think most people would be far less surprised by) but it would allow a significant amount of reasonable code. The paper has a lot more details.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Does the same *permitted result* rule also apply to example #3 (`[]<s = bool{}>{ return true; }()`)? Which would imply that both GCC and MSVC are wrong to accept it? Isn't there some rule that goes into NTTP references more specifically?

Comment: @303 That one's just a clang bug - there's no constexpr reference in that case. That's just binding a bool to a (non-constexpr) reference, which should be fine.

Comment: The only thing your answer is missing, is which rule in the standard should allow for the construct of `[]<s = bool{}>{}`. This could help with reporting the bug to Clang.